# How to resolve warning: "Unsupported Configuration: Tab Bar Controller NIB Name set to MainWindow.nib"?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to resolve this warning:

> Unsupported Configuration: Tab Bar Controller NIB Name set to MainWindow.nib (This view controller is not intended to have its view set in this manner)

?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    databaseName = @"RecipeDatabase.sql";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];
 [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

@EIJay :this is the method you mentioned , i am new to iOS so please will you suggest changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Storyboards, make sure the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate is only returning YES and not trying to initialize the window.

If this isn't the case, please post the code you are using in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: when i removed [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; i got "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" in debug area

Comment: Make sure you have set the Storyboard you created as the Main Storyboard in the App Info screen.

Comment: If this isn't the case, please post the code you are using in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
 
 databaseName = @"RecipeDatabase.sql";
 
 
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

 [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
 
 
 [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];
 
 
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

Comment: oops :P i had set NIB Name of tab bar controller wrong.. by correcting it my issue got fixed ..:) Thanks EIJay for ur suggestions .. :)